# In Flex 4.5, can a DataGroup have accessibilityEnabled for all of its individual items?

Tags: apache-flex, accessibility, itemrenderer, section508

I'm building a Flex app that has to be accessible and meet section 508 guidelines. Some pre-built parts of are making heavy use of DataGroup, DataGrid, and ItemRenderers. I can't get anything that was created with ItemRenderers to even receive keyboard focus, so it seems impossible to have their accessibilityProperties revealed.

Is there a trick to making focus available to an ItemRenderer? Or some alternative I could use?

Comment: I am not a Flex developer, but during my search the method `getCurrentRendererState()` and binding kept popping up. Maybe look into that abd see if you could throw a focus method in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I kind of stumbled across this, and I'm not entirely sure why this works, but the solution is simple. Just add `implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent"` into the root tag of the custom `ItemRenderer`, and then each item in the list will be able to receive focus and expose its `accessibilityProperties`.

The strange is, the Flex compiler doesn't complain if the custom renderer fails to implement the required `IFocusManagerComponent` methods. I don't know why, but I would speculate that these methods are implemented somewhere up the code chain, and aren't used unless a component explicity implements `IFocusManagerComponent`.

The only problem I'm having now is that only the visible items show their `accessibilityProperties`, which makes sense because `ItemRenderers` are only created for the visible items on screen, but I should find some way to scroll the list automaticaly if the last visible `ItemRenderer` loses focus.